# Prevent JLabel positions from resetting?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

[image: Pic]

On the left panel I want my JLabel to move around to random positions within the box and on the right panel I want my JLabel to be updated with the current time frequently while moving around to random positions within the box aswell.

The problem I'm receiving at the moment is, when I set the time and position of my JLabel, my JLabel in my left box bugs. It appears at it's initial position first (top of the box) before moving to it's random position every it's supposed to move.

I have a class that implements runnable that handles the left JLabel and another class that also implements runnable that handles the JLabel with time updates.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I would like this program to be set up this way, 2 classes implementing runnable that handles the JLabels moving.

This is the class that cares of the left panel:

```
public class MoveDisplay {
    private GUIFrame gui;
    private boolean moving = true;


    public MoveDisplay(GUIFrame gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public void start() {
        moving = true;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (moving) {
            int x = rand.nextInt(150) + 1;
            int y = rand.nextInt(150) + 1;

             java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() {

                        gui.moveDisplay(x, y, 100, 100);
                    }
                } );
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        moving = false;
    }
}
```

And this is the right panel which is the clock.

```
public class MoveClock {
        private GUIFrame gui;
        private boolean clock = true;
        private volatile boolean running = true;

        public MoveClock(GUIFrame gui) {
            this.gui = gui;
        }

        public void start() {
            clock = true;
            Random rand = new Random();
            while (clock) {

                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                  int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                  int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                 gui.Klockan(hour, minute, second);
                  int a = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                  int b = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

                  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //Utan detta så kör inte Klockan random placeringar
                        public void run() {

                            gui.moveClock(a, b, 150, 150);
                        }
                    } );


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            clock = false;
        }
    }
```

And this is where all the Frame,  Jpanels and so on class:

```
    private JLabel movingDisplay;
    private JLabel movingClock;
    private MP3Player mp3_player;
    private boolean playing = true;
    private boolean moving = true;
    private boolean clocking = true;
//  private Thread t1;
    JDialog playingDialog;
    private MoveDisplay moveDisplay;
    private MoveClock moveClock;

    Clip clip;

    /**
     * Starts the application
     */
    public void Start() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 494, 437);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("Multiple Thread Demonstrator");
        InitializeGUI(); // Fill in components
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false); // Prevent user from change size
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Start middle screen
        moveDisplay = new MoveDisplay(this);
        moveClock = new MoveClock(this);
    }

JPanel pnlDisplay = new JPanel();
        Border b2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Display Thread");
        pnlDisplay.setBorder(b2);
        pnlDisplay.setBounds(12, 118, 222, 269);
        pnlDisplay.setLayout(null);

        // Add buttons and drawing panel to this panel
        btnDisplay = new JButton("Start Display");
        btnDisplay.setBounds(10, 226, 121, 23);
        pnlDisplay.add(btnDisplay);

        btnDStop = new JButton("Stop");
        btnDStop.setBounds(135, 226, 75, 23);
        pnlDisplay.add(btnDStop);

        pnlMove = new JPanel();
        pnlMove.setBounds(10, 19, 200, 200);
        Border b21 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        pnlMove.setBorder(b21);
        pnlDisplay.add(pnlMove);
        // Then add this to main window
        frame.add(pnlDisplay);

        // The moving graphics outer panel
        JPanel pnlTriangle = new JPanel();
        Border b3 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Triangle Thread");
        pnlTriangle.setBorder(b3);
        pnlTriangle.setBounds(240, 118, 222, 269);
        pnlTriangle.setLayout(null);

        // Add buttons and drawing panel to this panel
        btnTriangle = new JButton("Start Rotate");
        btnTriangle.setBounds(10, 226, 121, 23);
        pnlTriangle.add(btnTriangle);

        btnTStop = new JButton("Stop");
        btnTStop.setBounds(135, 226, 75, 23);
        pnlTriangle.add(btnTStop);

        pnlRotate = new JPanel();
        pnlRotate.setBounds(10, 19, 200, 200);
        Border b31 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        pnlRotate.setBorder(b31);
        pnlTriangle.add(pnlRotate);
        // Add this to main window
        frame.add(pnlTriangle);



        movingDisplay = new JLabel("DisplayThread");
        pnlMove.add(movingDisplay);
        btnDStop.setEnabled(false);


        movingClock = new JLabel("TriangleThread");
        pnlRotate.add(movingClock);
        btnTStop.setEnabled(false);


        btnDisplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                moving = true;
                btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
                btnDStop.setEnabled(true);
                startMoveDisplay();
            }
        });

        btnDStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                moving = false;
                btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
                btnDStop.setEnabled(false);
                startMoveDisplay();
            }
        });

        btnTriangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                clocking = true;
                btnTriangle.setEnabled(false);
                btnTStop.setEnabled(true);
                startMoveClock();
            }
        });


    btnTStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            clocking = false;
            btnTriangle.setEnabled(true);
            btnTStop.setEnabled(false);
            startMoveClock();
        }
    });
}

    public void startMoveDisplay() {
        if(moving) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    moveDisplay.start();
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            moveDisplay.stop();
        }
    }

    public void startMoveClock() {
        if(clocking) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    moveClock.start();
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            moveClock.stop();
        }
    }

    public void moveDisplay(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        movingDisplay.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void moveClock(int a, int b, int width, int height) {
        movingClock.setBounds(a, b, width, height);
    }

    public void Klockan(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        movingClock.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    }
```

Comment: I see your code is working correctly in your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710527/cant-set-image-in-jlabel-from-anywhere-except-jframe/33710599#33710599. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. Or if you used a different solution then post your own answer, again, so people know the problem has been solved. Be thoughtful of people using the forum so we don't spend time answering questions that already have solutions.

Comment: @camickr  I didn't notice I was answered here. With this I got sorted of my problems and got everything to work :) Thank you!

Comment: Why did you delete your other question?. Did the answer not help solve the problem?

Comment: Nope but the answer here helped me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears at it's initial position first (top of the box) before moving to it's random position every it's supposed to move.

Well, your entire program uses a null layout (which is incorrect as Swing was designed to be used with layout managers), EXCEPT for the panel that you add the random label to.

```
    movingDisplay = new JLabel("DisplayThread");
    pnlMove.add(movingDisplay);
```

That is I don't see where you use `pnlMove.setLayout( null )`.

So I'm guessing the layout manager is temporarily invoked and the label is painted at the start of the panel before it is moved to its random location.

So my recommendations are:

1. Don't build the GUI using null layouts (except for the panel with the random location). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
2. Don't use a Thread and Thread.sleep(). For animation use a Swing Timer. When the Timer fires the code is executed on the EDT and you don't need the SwingUtilities.invokeLater().
3. All you want you code to do is change the location of the label, so just use the `setLocation(...)` method, not the setBounds() method.
4. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct. Be consistent! Notice how the forum is highlighting the method names like they are class names?